# How to display x-value(names) in barplot in R?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have the following data

```
r<-structure(list(Relation = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Neighbours", 
"Other known persons", "Parents/Close Family Members", "Relatives"
), class = "factor"), Number = c(539L, 2315L, 10782L, 18171L)), .Names = c("Relation", 
"Number"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

when I plot barplot using following command:

```
 barplot(r[,2],names.arg=r$Relation,col="green")
```

The x-value names under the Relation column name is not visible/shown in the plot. What is wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: Where is the `m` object referenced in your code? Replacing with `names.arg=letters[1:4]` seems to name the bars. Did you mean `barplot(r[,2],names.arg=r$Relation,col="green")`?

Comment: Yes Sir, basically, R skips the longer names in the x-axis I have changed the names to short here. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Make your plot wider. R doesn't like to overlap axis labels.

Comment: You could check `staxlab`, `barp` in `library(plotrix)`

Comment: that staggered option in staxlab is pretty nice (set `srt = NA`). you could also insert some `\n` into long labels (like `Parents/Close\nFamily Members` or `Other known\npersons`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try substituting a line feed for each space in names.arg:

```
barplot(r[,2],names.arg=gsub("\\s","\n", r$Relation),col="green", line=2)
```

[image]

(Needed to shift the labels down with the "line" parameter.)

Answer (score 4):

The answer to "what is wrong here" is in the comments. Here is a solution using `ggplot`, which does a much better job managing long names.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(r, aes(x=Relation, y=Number)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="lightgreen", color="grey50")
```

[image]

When you have long names like this sometimes it's better to use horizontal bars.

```
ggplot(r, aes(x=Relation, y=Number)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="lightgreen", color="grey50")+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]